# A fluid grid, without rounding errors, and multiple column widths

Tags: html, css, grid, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I've looked at all the hip, fluid-grid frameworks, and it seems like it's impossible to have a fluid grid that uses percentages for column widths (and ems for gutter widths), that is *divisible by 3*, and doesn't suffer from horrible rounding errors. Take a look:

http://roestudios.com/code/12-columns.html

Try resizing your browser window, and notice how things bounce around. Most gutters don't line up at all from row to row. This is because of the lack of tidy sub-pixel handling. Of course, rounding varies from browser to browser.

The example I've shown is based on a 12 column grid, which is ideal, since a 12 column grid allows for elements that are 1/4 and 1/3 the width of the page.

That's why something like [The Golden Grid](http://goldengridsystem.com/) won't work: it's not divisible by 3.

It's fairly standard to have a home page with a full width "main" area, and three "buckets" below. Standard layout.

But in trying to build "responsive sites," it seems like fixed-layouts with several @media queries might be the only real choice if I want elements to be pixel-perfectly aligned.

Edit: Much, much worse in Webkit, but even Firefox doesn't yield pixel-perfect results.

Comment: And why, exactly, do you seek "pixel-perfect results"?

Comment: Because I'm an anal designer who cares about the details.

Comment: The conclusion should be that : css "frameworks" are not for production use. You can use them to mock up a layout, but in final product there should be only css made by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CSS3 FlexBox? It works in Firefox but unfortunately still is a bit jumpy & not pixel perfect in Chrome..

http://jsfiddle.net/lukem/gqsCV/3/

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/